# Pandas .describe() only returning 4 statistics on int dataframe (count, unique, top, freq)... no min, max, etc

Tags: python, pandas

Why could this be? My data seems pretty simple and straightforward, it's a 1 column dataframe of ints, but .describe only returns count, unique, top, freq... not max, min, and other expected outputs.

(Note .describe() functionality is as expected in other projects/datasets)

Comment: Can you check whether the column is in fact integer by `df.dtypes`?

Comment: post the output from `df.info()` to prove your assertion,

Answer (score 18):

It seems pandas doesn't recognize your data as int.

Try to do this explicitly:

```
print(df.astype(int).describe())
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
df.agg(['count', 'nunique', 'min', 'max'])
```

You can add or remove the different aggregation functions to that list.
And when I have quite a few columns I personally like to transpose it:

```
df.agg(['count', 'nunique', 'min', 'max']).transpose()
```

To reduce the aggregations on a subset of columns you different ways to do it.

- By containig a word: example 'ID'

  df.filter(like='ID').agg(['count', 'nunique'])
- By type of data:

  df.select_dtypes(include=['int']).agg(['count', 'nunique'])

  df.select_dtypes(exclude=['float64']).agg(['count', 'nunique'])

Answer (score 1):

try to change your features into numerical values to return all the statics you need :

```
df1['age'] = pd.to_numeric(df1['age'], errors='coerce')
```